# Is there any way to track the monomorphization process of generics?

Tags: rust, rust-analyzer, rust-compiler-plugin

I find it is untrackable by just reading the plain source code, when the generic relationship is convoluted.

Is there any way to disclose the compiler's instantiation trajectory of a particular generic struct or function?

**Elaborated**:

Thanks for interesting in this quesion. It is elaborated here. I'm studying the Warp crate recently. So take it for example.

```rust
use warp::Filter;

async fn handler_without_parameter() -> Result<impl warp::Reply, warp::Rejection> {
    Ok(warp::reply::json(&"dumb".to_string()))
}

fn main() {
    let get_items = warp::get()
        .and(warp::path("/"))
        .and(warp::path::end())
        .and_then(handler_without_parameter); //Ok here
}
```

```rust
async fn handler_without_parameter() -> Result<impl warp::Reply, warp::Rejection> {
    Ok(warp::reply::json(&"dumb".to_string()))
}

fn main() {
    let para: HashMap<String, String> = HashMap::new();
    let para_filter = warp::any().map(move || para.clone()); // A filter with data

    let get_items = warp::get()
        .and(warp::path("/"))
        .and(warp::path::end())
        .and(para_filter)      //chain with the data filter
        .and_then(handler_without_parameter); // error[E0593]: function is expected to take 1 argument, but it takes 0 arguments
}
```

After chaining a filter( which taking along with data), the parameter of the method `and_then` is expected to take 1 argument. I'm curious about this requirement change for `and_then`, so I try to figure out the monomorphization course of this method.

https://docs.rs/warp/0.3.5/warp/trait.Filter.html#method.and_then

```rust
    fn and<F>(self, other: F) -> And<Self, F>
    where
        Self: Sized,
        <Self::Extract as Tuple>::HList: Combine<<F::Extract as Tuple>::HList>,
        F: Filter + Clone,
        F::Error: CombineRejection<Self::Error>,
    {
        And {
            first: self,
            second: other,
        }
    }


    fn and_then<F>(self, fun: F) -> AndThen<Self, F>
    where
        Self: Sized,
        F: Func<Self::Extract> + Clone,
        F::Output: TryFuture + Send,
        <F::Output as TryFuture>::Error: CombineRejection<Self::Error>,
    {
        AndThen {
            filter: self,
            callback: fun,
        }
    }
```

And the base trait is:

```rust
pub trait FilterBase {
    type Extract: Tuple; // + Send;
    type Error: IsReject;
    type Future: Future<Output = Result<Self::Extract, Self::Error>> + Send;

    fn filter(&self, internal: Internal) -> Self::Future;

    fn map_err<F, E>(self, _internal: Internal, fun: F) -> MapErr<Self, F>
    ...
}
```

I can't figure out why the added chaining could incur the requirement change of the `and_then` method, since, to me, the generics relation here is very convoluted.

Even with the hints provided by rust-analyzer, it doesn't help a lot, because the `Extract = ...` part is eclipsed.
[image]

Comment: Its not clear to me what you're looking for. Monomorphization is simplify filling the generic parameters with concrete types that are used; I'm not sure there's much "process" there. Are you just curious *when* its done? Or do you want a list of all sets of parameters that are compiled? Or are you interested in viewing the compiled output of a particular monomorphization?

Comment: @kmdreko Thanks for your interesting, I have elaborated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `para_filter` returns something, and the next function has to take what the previous function returns. So if `para_filter` returns a `HashMap<String, String>`, then `handler_without_parameter` must take `HashMap<String, String>` as its sole argument. If `para_filter` returned nothing, then `handler_without_parameter` would have to take an empty tuple as its sole argument (`handler_without_parameter(_: ()) -> ...`).

How I figured this out: the rather opaque error message

```
error[E0593]: function is expected to take 1 argument, but it takes 0 arguments
  --> src/main.rs:16:10
   |
4  | async fn handler_without_parameter() -> Result<impl warp::Reply, warp::Rejection> {
   | --------------------------------------------------------------------------------- takes 0 arguments
...
16 |         .and_then(handler_without_parameter); // error[E0593]: function is expected to take 1 argument, but it takes 0 arguments
   |          ^^^^^^^^ expected function that takes 1 argument
   |
   = note: required for `fn() -> impl Future<Output = Result<impl Reply, Rejection>> {handler_without_parameter}` to implement `warp::generic::Func<(HashMap<String, String>,)>`
```

The key is the last line, `note: required for ... {handler_without_parameter} to implement warp::generic::Func<(HashMap<String, String>,)>` which is cut off in your screenshot — when in doubt, best to always read the full compiler diagnostic. If you're using rust analyzer, then you can hover over an error and click “show full compiler diagnostic”.

As an aside, this does not have to do with monomorphization, but rather with generic functions whose input type and output type share a generic parameter and/or generic constraint. The argument to `and` affects the type of its output, which in turn affects the type of the object calling `and_then`, which in turn affects the type of the argument expected by `and_then`.